# Error while installing DaVinci Resolve version 17.4.6 on Ubuntu 20.04.4

Tags: software-installation, davinci-resolve

I got an error while installing DaVinci Resolve 17.4.6 on Ubuntu 20.04. After running MakeResolveDeb 1.6.0 I got this error.

```
MakeResolveDeb 1.6.0
Detected DaVinci Resolve version 17.4.6
Checking for tar...found!
Checking for fakeroot...found!
Checking for dpkg-deb...found!
Using Resolve 17 conversion process
Extracting archive
Found 2876 objects
Adding BlackmagicRAWPlayer
Adding BlackmagicRAWSpeedTest
Creating Debian package
**dpkg-deb: error: control directory has bad permissions 777 (must be >=0755 and <=0775)**
[DONE] errors reported 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I've finally figured out how to make this work repeatedly on **Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS** without workarounds.

You need to first update your Nvidia drivers directly from Nvidia.

There are a bunch of dependencies missing from Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS that prevent Resolve's installation. Here's how fix that.

First, run:

```
sudo apt install libfuse2
```

Then:

```
sudo apt install libapr1
sudo apt install libaprutil1
sudo apt install libxcb-composite0
```

Then:

```
sudo apt install libxcb-cursor0
sudo apt install libxcb-damage0
sudo apt install libxcb-xinerama0
sudo apt install libxcb-xinput0
```

Then open a console in your unzipped resolve folder and install as normal.

This works without black screens or other errors.

Comment: Did you know that you don't need to run `sudo apt install` over and over again if you need to install multiple packages? You can just list multiple packages, like this: `sudo apt install package1 package2 package3` and so on. Also, it's important to always run `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` to ensure the system is up-to-date before attempting to install new packages.

Comment: Finally, the advice *"You need to first update your Nvidia drivers directly from Nvidia"* - is really not recommended. The drivers that are posted on Nvidia's website are not tested  to work with Ubuntu. Installing Nvidia drivers this way also sidesteps your package manager. This makes it likely that problems will arise in the future when other updates break dependencies. Having installed the driver this way may have caused the original problem to begin with.